# Rotate image in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I am using a Symfony 2 liipImagineBundle and all i want to do is to rotate image 180 deg and then flip it. I just want to have a mirror view of my image. How can i do it with my imagine bundle or if it not possible ho to do it in Symfony 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom filter:
https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/filters.md#load-your-custom-filters

Use PHP function `imagerotate`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Comment: Can you show your implementation of image rotate filter, please?

Comment: Here the new [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/filters.html#load-your-custom-filters) for custom filters.